# Как добавить донат в приложение через Google Pay?

Tags: flutter

Как добавить донат в приложение?
Посмотрел плагин in_app_purchase, но что-то не разобрался, как можно это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала вам необходимо настроить billing в Google Play и App Store. Дальше вам необходимо настроить подключение к этим сервисам с помощью in_app_purchase. Добавить товар. Настроить взаимодействие между вашим товаром и сервисом.

Вот несколько статей на эту тему:

1. [Adding in-app purchases to Flutter apps](https://joebirch.co/flutter/adding-in-app-purchases-to-flutter-apps/)
2. [In App Purchases in Flutter](https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-inapp-purchases/)